# Comparing lists in Standard ML

Tags: list, sml

I am extremely new to SML and we just got out first programming assignment for class and I need a little insight.

The question is: write an ML function, called `minus: int list * int list -> int list`, that takes two non-decreasing integer lists and produces a non-decreasing integer list obtained by removing the elements from the first input list which are also found in the second input list.

For example,

```
minus( [1,1,1,2,2], [1,1,2,3] ) = [1,2]

minus( [1,1,2,3],[1,1,1,2,2] ) = [3]
```

Here is my attempt at answering the question. Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly? I don't quite understand parsing lists.

```
fun minus(xs,nil) = []
| minus(nil,ys) = []
| minus(x::xs,y::ys) = if x=y then minus(xs,ys) else x :: minus(x,ys);
```

Here is a fix I just did, I think this is right now?

```
fun minus(L1,nil) = L1
| minus(nil,L2) = []
| minus(L1,L2) = if hd(L1) > hd(L2) then minus(L1,tl(L2))
    else if hd(L1) = hd(L2) then minus(tl(L1),tl(L2))
    else hd(L1) :: minus(tl(L1), L2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your fix is correct. Exploiting the fact that two lists xs and ys are sorted, we have:

- If the head of xs is bigger than the head of ys, xs' head can occur
  in ys' tail.
- If the head of xs is the same as the head of ys, we
  remove both two heads.
- If the head of xs is smaller than the head of    ys, xs' head
  couldn't occur in ys and we put it to the result    list.

However, I have some minor comments on your function:

- `[]` and `nil` are the same. I think it's more clear to use `[]` only.
- Variables indicating lists are usually in a form of xs, ys,... (lowercase ending with "s").
- You should break down the list using `::` (cons) constructor rather than using functions like `hd` and `tl`.

Here is an improved version:

```
fun minus(xs, []) = xs
  | minus([], ys) = []
  | minus(x::xs, y::ys) = if x > y then minus(x::xs, ys)
                          else if x = y then minus(xs, ys)
                          else x::minus(xs, y::ys)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a type in your else-clause:

```
x :: minus(x,ys)
```

That second `x` should be `xs`.

Comment: That works better but now as you can see on the examples I posted, the answer for the second one is just [3] and I get [2,3]. I don't get how I could have each number in the first list compare to each number in the second list.

Comment: @user: You don't need to compare each number from one list to each number in the other list. You can do it (and are probably supposed to) while going through each list only once. Specifically the fact that you "forget" both x and y if they are not equal is wrong. You need to use the property that the lists are sorted.